# Subsequence convergence epsilon definition with and without $v_k$: Why equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have two definitions for the convergence of a subsequence. The first one is the obvious one:

*First Definition* (with $v_k:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ [stricly monotonic increasing])

$\forall \varepsilon >0\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall k\ge N \colon |a_{v_k}-A|<\varepsilon$

*Second Definition* (without $v_k$)

$\forall \varepsilon >0\forall N\in \mathbb{N}\exists n\ge N\colon |a_n -A|<\varepsilon $

**Equivalence**

These both are equivalent.

(I tried something like the following, but that didn't seem to lead the way: Comming from the first definition:
$v(k)=n \iff k=v^{-1}(n)$

$\forall \varepsilon >0\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall v^{-1}(n)\ge N \colon |a_{n}-A|<\varepsilon$

$\iff \forall \varepsilon >0\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall n\ge v(N) \colon |a_{n}-A|<\varepsilon$

$\iff \forall \varepsilon >0\exists v(N)\in \mathbb{N} \forall n\ge N \colon |a_{n}-A|<\varepsilon$

$\iff \forall \varepsilon >0\exists v(N)\in \mathbb{N} \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \colon n\ge v(N) \implies |a_{n}-A|<\varepsilon$

$\implies \forall \varepsilon >0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\exists v(N)\in \mathbb{N}  \colon n\ge v(N) \implies |a_{n}-A|<\varepsilon$
)

Is someone able to show, why they are equivalent?

Comment: IMVHO they aren't. Suppose $(v_k)$ is a sequence of all even numbers; then you can tell nothing about terms of $(a_n)$ sequence at odd positions. However, if there is an assumption (which you didn't say), that the definition requirement must hold for **each** monotonic increasing sequence $(v_k)$, then it is sufficient to apply $v_k=k$ and the subsequence definition gets reduced to the standard one.

Comment: @CiaPan Note the difference in the quantifiers.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't reading carefully enough. Fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first definition says:

$$\forall \varepsilon >0\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\ \forall k\ge N \colon |a_{v_k}-A|<\varepsilon$$

—for arbitrarily small neighborhood $B(A,ε)$ of $A$, bounded by the distance $ε$ from $A$ (i.e. $B(A,ε)=\{x:\lvert x-A\rvert < ε\}$), there exists such length (number of terms) $N$, that – after dropping initial $N$ terms from the $(v_k)$ sequence, all the remaining terms of subsequence $(a_{v_k})$ fall into the $B(A,ε)$.

Let's define a shortened sequence $u_k = v_{k-N}$. Then we have, for the same arbitrary ε, there exists a sequence $(u_k)$ of indices, such that:
$$\forall k\in\mathbb N :  |a_{u_k}-A|<ε$$
—all terms of subsequence $(a_{u_k})$, defined by the indexing sequence $(u_k)$, belong to $B$.

However, the $u$ sequence is strictly increasing, which property it inherits from $v$ sequence. That means its each term is at least greater by $1$ than the previous one, which in turn inductively implies $u_k \ge k$.

So there are infinitely many items of $(a)$ belonging to $B$ and they are at arbitrarily large positions. That means, for arbitrary large $M$ there exists a number $m = u_M \ge M$, such that $a_m\in B$, as the second definition requires:
$$\forall ε>0\ \forall M\in \mathbb{N}\ \exists m\ge M: |a_m -A|<ε$$
(Symbols replaced to avoid confusion – the same symbol does not necessarily mean the same value in both definitions!)

Now let's start from the second definition:

$$\forall ε>0\ \forall M\in \mathbb{N}\ \exists m\ge M: |a_m -A|<ε$$

—for arbitrarily small neighborhood $B$ of $A$ there exists a term $a_m$ of sequence $(a_n)$ at arbitrarily large index $m$ ($m>M$ for arbitrarily large $M$), which belongs to $B$.

Now, given any $ε$, for every natural $M$ let's choose appropriate $m$ and define a sequence $(m_M)_{M\in\mathbb N}$. This is not necessarily strictly increasing, however, it is bounded from below by $M$ (each term is greater than or equal to its own index: $m_M \ge M$).

This leads to an iterative definition of sequence $(j_n)$:
$$j_M = \begin{cases}m_1 & \text{for }M=1 \\ m_{(j_{M-1}+1)}  & \text{for }M>1\end{cases}$$
—we start with the first term of $(m)$ sequence to the $(j)$ sequence, then we choose the next term of $(m)$ at position greater than the last defined $(j)$ term (index $j_{M-1}+1$ to the $(m)$ sequence). This makes the $(j)$ sequence strictly increasing, because each term of $(m)$ is greater than or equal to its own index:
$$j_M = m_{(j_{M-1}+1)} \ge j_{M-1}+1 > j_{M-1} $$

All terms of $(j)$ were choosen from the sequence $(m)$, and all terms of $(m)$ satisfy:
$$a_m \in B$$
hence the sequence $(j)$ satisfies requirements of the first definition: it is a strictly increasing sequence of indices, such that almost all (in fact, all) terms of $(a)$ indexed by values of $(j)$ belong to $B$:
$$\exists N=1\in\mathbb N\ \forall k\ge N: a_{j_k}\in B$$

We can see that if a sequence $(a)$ and number $A$ satisfy requirements of one definition, they also satisfy requirements of the other one, hence definitions are equivalent.